# Prove $S$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ $\iff$ it has betweenness

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

The definition of betweenness is given as:

> If $x \in S$, $y \in S$, and $x < z < y$, then $z \in S$.

However, I don't know the formal definition of interval in $\mathbb{R}$, which makes it difficult for me to prove this. I obviously know of the intuitive notion of interval, like $2 \leq 4 < 6$ or something, but I don't know how to express it in general.

So if I want to prove that for $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, $S \neq \varnothing$, if $S$ is an interval, then $S$ has betweenness, I don't know what to make as an assumption. Also for the converse (since it's an if and only if statement), I don't know how to prove something is an interval.

Comment: This is sometimes taken to be the definition of *interval*. Clearly that’s not the case here, so I can only guess that you’re expected to define intervals in $\Bbb R$ to be the sets of the forms $(a,b),(a,b]$, and $[a,b)$ for $a<b$, $[a,b]$ for $a\le b$, and $(\leftarrow,a),(\leftarrow,a],(a,\to)$, and $[a,\to)$.

Comment: Perhaps your definition of interval just any connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Because this is basically Theorem 2.47, p. 42 in Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think you are right. Since there is no "general" form of these 8 forms of intervals, what should I do in this case for the proof? Do 8 separate cases?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: It depends on how fussy the grader is. I think that if you do a careful job with $[a,b)$ and one of the rays, you've demonstrated that you know what you're doing and ought to be able to say that the other cases are similar.